# How can I create a config file for AWS RDS credentials and import them in my AWS Lambda APIs?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, pymysql

Apologies if the question seems too basic as I'm new to AWS. I need help with creating a config file where I can store my RDS credentials and import this file inside my Lambda functions instead of writing the credentials inside each of them. The Lambda API connects to the RDS using the following credentials:

```
#rds settings
rds_host  = "<host url>"
name = '<host name>'
password = '<host password>'
db_name = '<name of the schema being used>'
```

I want to put this information in a config file but I'm not able to figure out where to place this config file inside AWS and how I can import the same. The reason I want to configure this is because if I change the credentials, I want them to be reflected inside each of my Lambdas.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Putting db credentials inside your lambda function is **not a good practice**. I would recommend following good practices and considering one of the following ways of passing db credentials into a lambda function:

1. Use [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) of lambda function to pass the credentials. The environment variables can even be [encrypted using KMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/security-dataprotection.html#security-privacy-intransit) for extra security.
2. Use [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) to centrally store and mange the credentials (free).
3. Use [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html) to store and automatically rotate the db credentails (not free).
4. Use [IAM Database Authentication for MySQL and PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html), which eliminates the use of traditional username and password for accessing a db.

If you have many lambda functions, then methods 2, 3 and 4 would be most suited. The methods also solve the problem of updating db credentials.